# idangerous swiper form focus iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, forms, swiper.js

I'm experiencing some difficulties using the **idangerous swiper**. I'm using the swiper to navigate between views on a mobile web app and it works great!
This is the code i use:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    loop:false,
    grabCursor: false,
    paginationClickable: false,
    moveStartThreshold:50
});
```

**The problem**
On two of the pages I hav input fields. When I tap these on my iPhone the keyboard appears but the input field loses focus. Then i have to click the form once again to get focus, enabling me to type in the field. I have no styling on the input fields and their markup looks like this:

```
<form action=""> 
    <input type="text" name="fname"><br> 
    <input type="text" name="lname"><br> 
    <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br> 
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

I think this could have something to do with some preventDefault of the idangerous swiper but I  have no proof of that.